# WinForm - DataGridView when row change event

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have an event set for RowHeaderMouseClick when I click on the header, my textbox is populated with data from the DataGrid.  I want to make my textbox populate when I select the row instead of the header.  Ideally, I want to hide the header.  What is the correct event/property that I need to set to achieve this?

Edit:
Attaching screenshot

[image]

Comment: What do you want to populate the textbox with? An item of data already in the grid? Show the code you have already

Comment: Have you looked at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter?view=net-5.0

Comment: Yes, an item that is already in the dataset

Comment: @Prateek I'm not sure I'd use that one.. actually I'm not sure I'd use one at all, if it's a databound grid

Comment: could you please add your code,  your `edit/update` method

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this for any event

```
//Handle RowChanged.
table.RowChanged += table_RowChanged;

//RowChanged Event.
static void table_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("... Changed:  " + (int)e.Row["Dosage"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it with events, as you seem to be saying that the textbox gets populated with an item from the row. In such a case you would have:

- your datagridview bound to a bindingsource
- your bindingsource bound to a datatable or other list that supports binding
- your textbox's text property bound to the same bindingsource

Every time the user clicks a row in the grid (or uses the keyboard to move to another row) they are causing the Current property of the bindingsource to update. This in turn changes any of the textboxes that are bound to true same binding source (a textbox only shows the current row item to which it is bound)

For a quick demo of how this works, do these steps (apologies I can't make any screenshots - I'm on a cellphone) - skip any steps you've already done

- add a DataSet type file to your project
- open it and right click the surface, add a datatable and name it eg Person
- right click it and add a couple of columns eg FirstName and LastName
- save
- switch to the form
- open the Dat Sources window (view menu, other windows)
- drag the Person node to the form, a datagridview appears as well as some other stuff (bindingsource) - look at the DataSource property of the grid
- in the Data sources window again click the drop down button next to Person, change it to details
- drag the person node to the form again, this time textboxes appear; take a look at their Text bindings in the (data bindings) section of their properties - they're bound to the same bindingsource as the grid is
- run the project, type 4 names into the grid and then select different rows at random using the mouse; the textboxes update to stay current with the grid selection

If this isn't the way you've done things up to now you should consider making it the way; using the DataSet designer to create strongly typed datatables is an easy way to model the data aspects of your program and there is a lot of tooling set up to make life easier when you use them to make a data driven app. If you've been putting data directly into a datagridview it's something you should avoid going forward, and instead separate your concerns in a more mvc style pattern

Comment: @Carius - He is using WinForms

Comment: I am always looking for ways to improve my code.  I tried following your steps earlier today and ran into a similar problem.  I changed my project and followed your steps.  I'm running into a similar issue still.  when I select the row and attempt to use my button to edit/update the record I get an error that I do not have an item selected.  I'll edit my post and post a screenshot.

Comment: Something there isn't arranged in the same way I've described: if it was your textbox would already be filled with the report data because you've selected a row in the grid. Maybe make a new quick test project and follow the steps I gave, and then you can know how it works, and you can see any differences between your setup currently and the new one. If you post some screenshots of the forms designer, the properties grid of the datagridview (showing the DataSource line) and the text box (showing the databindings expanded) it will help us see more

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove or make the `rowHeader` invisible

You can SET an Event `DataGridView CellClick` and below is the CODE

```
//Im Assuming that we are getting the row VALUES
try{
 int rowIndex = e.RowIndex; //getting the position of ROW in DGV when CLick
 int columns = Columns.Count//numebr of Columns

 for(int i=0; i< columns;i++)
 {
 //Here we can populate textBoxes and using FlowLayoutPanel
  string values = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Columns[i].Value.toString();

 //Creating new TextBox

TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
txtBox.Text = values;
txtBox.Size = new Size(100,200);

flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txtBox);


 }

}catch(Exception ee){}
```

OR If you want to pass the VALUES of the selected ROW you can do like this

```
textBox.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Columns[0].Value.toString();//1st col
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Columns[1].Value.toString();//2nd col
```

Answer (score 0):

First, right-click your `dataGrid` and select `properties`

Then change the `SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect` if you like as shown below:

[image]

Next, In the `datagrid` event section double-click on `SelectionChanged`
and write code like this, you can use other events, although

[image]

```
   // Just for example
    private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null && dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index >= 0)
            {

                var row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
                txtCode.Text = (row.Cells["code"].Value != null) ? row.Cells["code"].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
                txtFirstName.Text = (row.Cells["firstName"].Value != null) ? row.Cells["firstName"].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
                txtLastName.Text = (row.Cells["lastName"].Value != null) ? row.Cells["lastName"].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```